# How can I retrieve Kafka messages inside a controller in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

The messages created by the producer are all being consumed as expected.
The thing is, I need to create an endpoint to retrieve the latest messages from the consumer.
Is there a way to do it?
Like an on-demand consumer?

I found this SO post but is only to consume the last N records. I want to consume the latest without caring about the offsets.

[Spring Kafka Consumer, rewind consumer offset to go back 'n' records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56953784/spring-kafka-consumer-rewind-consumer-offset-to-go-back-n-records/56954463)

I'm working with Kotlin but if you have the answer in Java I don't mind either.

Comment: Consumers should be long-running. What do you mean "on demand"? If you don't care about offsets, just use `consumer.seekToEnd`

Comment: "On demand" means "on demand", as in, whenever I call certain function, etc. But don't worry, ChatGPT already gave me the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to create listener containers dynamically; you can then start/stop them on demand. To get the records back into the controller, you'd need to use something like a blocking queue, or make the controller itself a `MessageListener`.

These answers show a couple of techniques for creating containers on demand:

[How to dynamically create multiple consumers in Spring Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55311070/how-to-dynamically-create-multiple-consumers-in-spring-kafka/55315537#55315537)

[Kafka Consumer in spring can I re-assign partitions programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69465733/kafka-consumer-in-spring-can-i-re-assign-partitions-programmatically/69466302#69466302)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Dynamic consumers is what actually helped me